# Sharing an image from url in marshmallow

Tags: android

My old code was only working well till lolipop. i tried to write a new one but its not working in marshmallow either. I been sitting on this for the last two days and i dont have a clue :(.

```
public void share(View view){
niv1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNetwork);
File file = getLocalBitmapFile(niv1);
Uri bmpUrii = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myfileprovider", file);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUrii);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "share");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Datas.Address);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
    } 

public File getLocalBitmapFile(NetworkImageView imageView) {

Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bmp = null;
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
} else {
    return null;
}
File bmpUri = null;

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
try {
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return file;
}
```

Comment: you have to get run time permission for accessing device storage from user. Have u implement?

Comment: yes. i have added

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: this is the one in manifeast file am asking about run time permission check here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: how to add this

Comment: i assume that your targetSdkVersion is 23 or above. check https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions and  http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

Comment: `Sharing an image from url`?? From url? I see nowhere an url.

Comment: its loaded in networkid

Comment: @Nas thanks bro. it works . just needed to add permissions.

Comment: you are welcome